# How to share files or image from iphone to iphone otherthan airdrops

Tags: ios

Transfer files between `iOS` and `non-iOS` devices.The above mentioned file sharing options are only available among `iOS` devices. When sharing files with other devices (`Android`, Windows Phone, etc.), you have two options here as well – via the Internet or via `WiFi` (without Internet).

Comment: Check Multipeer connectivity, it's the technology at the bottom of airdrop

Comment: Your subject line says "iPhone to iPhone" but then you talk about Android and Windows.  What, exactly, do you need?

Comment: I want to share text or image from iphone to another device.

Comment: Thank U Andrea. Its working Fine